# How to use the ascent letters as alphabet letters too in a search function

Tags: java, android, regex, pattern-matching

Say for eg:

```
String searchFunction = "Cόstome"
```

Expectation:
When I type ό, it's highlighting only ό but I need to highlight alphabet o too in the above string.

What I tried is,

```
handleFilterChange(deAccent(filterTerm));

public String deAccent(String str) {
        String nfdNormalizedString = Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+");
        return pattern.matcher(nfdNormalizedString).replaceAll("");
    }
```

But the above code is replacing the special characters to alphabets.
 ie when i type ό, it's not highlighting ό but it's highlighting alphabet o.

My expectation requirement is,  it should highlight and consider both special character and alphabet o when i type special character  ό.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly, you want to have both charcter `o` and special symbol `ό` getting detected within your search pattern.

Here with your specific string pattern search `String searchFunction = "Cόstome"`you are only searching for a specific string.
If you have only 2 type of strings `Cόstome` & `Costome` then you can use below search string to look for both.

```
String searchFunction = "C[όo]stome"
```

This will search for both character and the special symbol with a fixed length of 1.

Let me know if that serves your purpose.

Comment: No bro. My requirement is, i have search field. When I type special character ό, it should detect both special character and also normal alphabet character from the given string. Whereas when i type, alphabet character 0, it should not detect special character